# Stopping tex-shell from opening when compiling Latex from Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, dot-emacs

How can I prevent the *tex-shell* buffer from opening when I compile Latex from Emacs?  It splits the window in half, and I always just use C-x 1 to get rid of it immediately.

The solution is possibly related to

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names ("*tex-shell*"))
```

which makes the new buffer take up the whole frame instead of just half (not what I want).

I tried the following, but it has no effect for Latex:

```
(defadvice compilation-start
    (around inhidbit-display (command &optional mode name-function highlight-regexp))
    (flet (display-buffer) (fset 'display-buffer 'ignore) ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'compilation-start)
(ad-deactivate 'compilation-start)
```

Comment: I don't think so.  The mode is "LaTeX".  Actually, I only have this problem on OS X.  On Ubuntu, the mode is "LaTeX/P", and tex-shell doesn't open.

Comment: What major mode does `C-h m` say you are in?

Comment: "LaTeX mode: Major mode for editing files of input for LaTeX."

Answer (score 2):

Well, you really should be using AUCTeX since it's much better.  Nevertheless if you type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and then a key sequence Emacs will tell you what would be run.  In this case, for <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>, it's `tex-file` so you will have to advise `tex-file`, or maybe (digging down into the source a little bit) `tex-start-shell`.

Comment: FYI: "AUCTex" is an emacs package that you can install that enhances the Latex edititing experience in Emacs. I highly suggest installing it, since it achieves the desired behaviour.
AUCTex is not a latex "compiler", just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following defun:

```
(defun tex-without-changing-windows ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (save-window-excursion (tex-file)))
```

I bind it to `C-c C-f` to replace `tex-file`.

Comment: can you walk through how to bind it to `C-c C-f`?

Comment: One way would be to overwrite the binding in the tex's major mode map (warning, untested code):

`(eval-after-load 'tex-mode '(define-key tex-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f") #'my-tex-file-replacement))`

more info: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-to-override-major-mode-bindings, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41617/672